# Directory index of "/var/www/html" is forbidden docker/nginx 403 error

Tags: docker, nginx

I think I've set up everything right in my nginx config which is built in docker-compose.yml. However, from tailing nginx logs it shows that

```
*1 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden
```

This results in a 403 forbidden page. I think I have set up permissions for www-data user properly, but maybe not.

Directory structure:

```
  src/
    - docker-compose.yml
    - .gitignore
    backend
        src
        - Dockerfile
        - package.json
        - .gitignore
    data
        nginx
        - nginx.conf
    frontend
        src
        - Dockerfile
        - package.json
        - .gitignore
```

docker-compose:

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: example
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example1234
      POSTGRES_DB: example
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /frontend {
        proxy_pass http://example:8080;
        try_files $uri /public/index.html;
    }

    location /backend {
        proxy_pass http://example:3000;
    }

    location /db {
        proxy_pass http://example:5432;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Permissions updated:

ls -l /var/www/

```
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 6 root www-data 4096 Feb 15 15:44 html
```

ls -l /var/www/html/

```
total 200
drwxrwxrwx 3 root www-data   4096 Feb 15 15:44 backend
drwxrwxrwx 3 root www-data   4096 Feb 15 14:25 data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data    736 Feb 15 15:44 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxrwx 6 root www-data   4096 Feb 15 15:44 frontend
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data 186352 Feb 15 15:44 package-lock.json
```

Update: fixed the 403 error by correctly directing to the index.html file inside /frontend/public/index.html. Still having errors with the app deploying to the server, though.

Comment: Have you checked files permissions?

Comment: Yeah I think they're fine according to my edited original post. Any ideas?

Comment: I think my nginx config might be trying to find the index page and it isn't properly listed. My index page is located inside of my react app which is in my root /var/www/html/frontend/public/index.html. How would I go about correctly pointing to that directory in my nginx location?

Comment: Update: no more 403 errors, but when I load the site I am sent back to the default "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." Could there be something wrong with my docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this problem is not related to docker. Can you please add some screenshots to question

Comment: Yeah no problem, what do you need screenshots of? My site is just showing the standard react-app index page.

Comment: As far as I remember, there was no solution. I never got a reply to what I asked.